# determine if output is string or integer

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, string

I am trying to write a script which connects to a database then run a query that returns count of rows in a table. sometimes database or table have problems and instead of an integer they return an error. for example:
`A database connection does not exist`
i want to determine if output is the integer i want or its an error. i searched through various posts but none of them worked in my script. what should i do?

```
DB2PATH=/bin/db2
$DB2PATH connect to $1 >> /dev/null
count=$($DB2PATH -x " select count(*) from TEST122 ")


if ! [[ "$count" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo "string"
else
    echo $count
fi
```

i changed the if condition in many different ways. i used `-eq` and `-ne`. it keep returning `string`. and the value of `count` is 11.

update:
`printf '%s' "$count" | hexdump -c`
output:

```
0000000                                       1   1
000000b
```

Comment: If `count` is actually `11`, the `if` works fine for me. Maybe the command output has spaces in it, or quotes, or some other weird characters.

Comment: @BlackCrystal: Can you do `printf '%s' "$count" | hexdump -c` and paste above?

Comment: @Inian what does that command do? i edited my post

Comment: @BlackCrystal: As muru has indicated in his comment, the variable has some extra spaces present, that's why you see it is matching the string type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the variable `count` has some extra undesirable spaces which is causing your condition to fail it to be an integer type.

You need to strip out the extra spaces in your variable to fix it. Use an external tool like `xargs` to remove the spaces. The useful thing with `xargs` is it swallows up both leading and trailing spaces in the variable.

```
if ! [[ $( xargs <<< "$count" ) =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo "string"
else
    echo $count
fi
```

If not for an external tool like `xargs` use the parameter expansion provided by the shell itself

```
if ! [[ "${count// /}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo "string"
else
    echo $count
fi
```

The syntax `${count// /}` will replace all the spaces with an empty string and the resultant string is used in the comparison with the regular expression defined.

Comment: You could also use the arithmetic context: `(( count = count ))` will succeed and convert `count` to a number if it didn't have invalid characters (leading, trailing spaces are fine). It will fail with invalid characters, so you could do `if (( count = count )); then echo "$count"; else echo string; fi`

Comment: @muru, that's both wrong and dangerous, `(( count = count ))` returns true if `$count` contains an artihmetic expression that resolves to a non-0 number. So it returns false for 0 even though that's a valid decimal number, and true for RANDOM (most likely), `1 + a[$(reboot)0]` (which also reboots), `PATH=123`...

Comment: Note that your first one would think that `'1'\2"3"` or `-n 123` (with some `echo` implementations) is a valid number. The second one would think that `1 2 34` is a valid number.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas woah. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @muru, see also [Security Implications of using unsanitized data in Shell Arithmetic evaluation](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/172103)

Answer (score 3):

To ignore and trim leading and trailing whitespace around the number:

```
if [[ $count =~ ^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
  echo number
  count=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo other
fi
```

Or with standard `sh` syntax:

```
trimmed=${count#"${count%%[![:space:]]*}"}
trimmed=${trimmed%"${count##*[![:space:]]}"}
case $trimmed in
  ("" | *[![:digit:]]*) echo other;;
  (*) echo number; count=$trimmed;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting negation inside expresion gives me correct results:

```
if [[ ! "$count" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
    echo "string"
else
    echo $count
fi
```